# How can I create a PDF or SVG file from the canvas area in the JavaFX App?

Tags: java, javafx

I want to ask you for help.

I am trying to create a pdf or svg file from the canvas area in the JavaFX application.

`PrinterJob.createPrinterJob()` always returns `null`. Because I do not have a printer installed locally.

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: What good would a `svg` do? Of course you could include rasterized images into a `svg` file but if this is the only thing that's in there, it's pretty pointless, since you could simply save this to a regular image file, e.g. a `.png` file. As for `pdf`. Choose a library capable of creating a pdf and do some research on how to include an image there... You won't be able to create vector graphics from a `Canvas` (which is rasterized) unless you apply image processing techniques to identify shapes.

Comment: OK, you are right. Which library?

Comment: Choose one... itext, pdfbox, ... (there are probably more out there...)

Answer (score 1):

you need pdfbox libraries https://archive.apache.org/dist/pdfbox/2.0.8/pdfbox-app-2.0.8.jar
put the canvas in pane node

```
package nodetopdf;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.SnapshotParameters;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.image.WritableImage;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.PDImageXObject;


public class NodeToPdf extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

 Button btn = new Button();
 btn.setTranslateY(100);
 btn.setText("To Pdf'");

Canvas canvas = new Canvas(200, 200);
 Pane pane = new Pane(canvas);

 Rectangle rectangle1 = new Rectangle(100, 50, Color.RED);

 pane.getChildren().addAll(rectangle1,btn);





btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {


    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println(" button pressed");
        WritableImage nodeshot = pane.snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(), 
 null);
        File file = new File("pane.png");

 try {
 ImageIO.write(SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(nodeshot, null), "png", file);
 } catch (IOException e) {

 }

        PDDocument doc    = new PDDocument();
        PDPage page = new PDPage();
        PDImageXObject pdimage;
        PDPageContentStream content;
        try {
            pdimage = PDImageXObject.createFromFile("pane.png",doc);
            content = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page);
            content.drawImage(pdimage, 100, 100);
            content.close();
            doc.addPage(page);
            doc.save("pdf_file.pdf");
            doc.close();
            file.delete();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(NodeToPdf.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
});


StackPane root = new StackPane();


root.getChildren().add(pane);




Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 600);


primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.show();
}}
```

Comment: It is probably best to use the latest stable version, which as of now is 2.0.11. If you're using some kind of dependency or build tool (such as Maven or Gradle) you can have it automatically get the latest release.